# jQuery removing hash value from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, fragment-identifier

I have a hard coded URL like so:

```
https://bupacouk.bwa.local.internal.bupa.co.uk/cash-plan-quote/quoteAction.do?getBenefitLevelDetails=getBenefitLevelDetails&productPolicyId=7841#a1
```

When Javascript is enabled i don't want the hash value on the end so how do i remove it?

When Javascript is disabled it needs to be present.

Thanks.

### EDIT

Here is the AJAX jQuery that i am using.  So i am pasisng the hard coded URL to the same page on the server and retrieving a table from it:

```
        // Find href of current tab
    var $tabValue = $(this).attr('href');

    // AJAX new table in
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(data){

        // Find benefit wrap
        $(data).find('.benefitWrap').each(function(){
            // get the contents
            var $benefitWrap = $(this).html();
            // replace contents on page
            $('.benefitWrap').replaceWith($('<div class="benefitWrap">' + $benefitWrap + '</div>'));

        });

       }

    });
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What is your jQuery like?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### original

It depends on what the hash value does. If it just moves the document down to `#a1`, you just need to set `scrollTop` to 0 after document has been loaded probably.

#### edit

looking on other stackoverflow questions,

```
parent.location.hash = ''
```

should do it, but *maybe* reloads the page (you have to test it)

Other than that, I advice you to handle it during/before your AJAX calls - i.e.

```
if (hash != 'a1'){ doAjax(); } //pseudocode obviously.
```

#### edit 2 with code based on posted code

Or, if you just need to call AJAX with `url` *without* hash, you can delete it in string, that calls the jQuery, no?

```
var $tabValue = $(this).attr('href');
var $withoutHash = $tabValue.substr(0,$tabValue.indexOf('#'));
```

we basically get a's `href` before first `#`

Comment: I need to remove it totaly as it is causing some AJAX to fail.

Answer (score 14):

A simple `window.location.hash=""` will do it.

Comment: There is no need for you to be using jQuery to execute this statement.

Comment: hmm.. this is leaving me with mypage.htm# ... am i missing something? i'd like to see mypage.htm

Comment: With this solution, some browsers leave the hash on the end, and some don't.

Answer (score 8):

This might be helpful to someone asking the same question, how to pull the data following a # in a href.

```
this.hash.slice(1);
```

This will give #123 as 123.

---

Edit: I should probably note, if you're going to be calculating numbers from this data, best to use `parseInt(this.hash.slice(1));` or else you'll get funky results.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. I have added a `!` to prevent the page from scrolling up.

```
window.location.hash="!";
```

Comment: That's great.  Cannot believe I asked this question almost ten years ago lol