# How to remove #name from URL?

Tags: html, url

I have a site which has a inner hyperlink `http://www.example.com/#name`. I want to change it to `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: Place the cursor at the end and press the backspace key 5 times. (You might want to provide more information about the circumstances and environment you want to do this in).

Comment: @david: too much silly answer i guess from your side.

Comment: Please be more elaborate. what is your requirement? do you wanna remove #using javascript

Comment: Can you rephrase the question please. Do you want the link to stop going to #name (in which case see @Tom Gullen's answer) or do you want it to go to the #name anchor but no show #name in the address bar after the page has been loaded (in which case see @Coding-Freak's answer)?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just in HTML, you need to just simply stop linking to `#name` and link to the root instead.  Go through all your anchor links and remove the reference to `#name`.

If you have access to dynamic server side languages, you can dynamically filter the content based on a cookie/session/querystring thus removing the need for named anchors.

Answer (score 0):

your question is similar to this stackoverflow.com post:
[jQuery removing hash value from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385897/jquery-removing-hash-value-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

java:  `url.substring(0, url.indexOf("#"));`