# How to change a <select> element back to the default value when hitting the back button?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, default, forms, back-button

I have a `<select>` element, used for navigation. You click on it to choose a page to go to, and when clicked it goes to that page. Here is the code for it:

```
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
    <option value="/item1" selected>Item 1</option>
    <option value="/item2" selected>Item 2</option>
    <option value="/item3" selected>Item 3</option>
</select>
```

When I use it, it goes to the page correctly, however when hitting the back button, the dropdown has the page I went to selected already. For example, if I'm on Item 1, and select Item 2, then go back to Item 1 through the browser's back button, Item 2 is selected in the list, which is kind of confusing.

How can I get it to switch back to the default value?

Comment: i think the back button of a browser will show a cached copy of the page and nat actually reload the page. i think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset your selection box to the default value and then navigate to the new page.  Here's an example of how to do that.

```
<script>
fix_ipad = function(evt){
    go_to = document.getElementById('go_to');
    go_to.selectedIndex = 0; // reset to default value before leaving current page
};

window.addEventListener("pagehide",fix_ipad,false);

goto_page_and_reset_default = function(){
    go_to = document.getElementById('go_to');
    go_to_page = go_to.value;
    go_to.selectedIndex = 0; // reset to default value before leaving current page

    window.open(go_to_page,"_top");    

}
</script>

<select onchange="goto_page_and_reset_default()" id='go_to'>
    <option value="/item1" selected>Item 1</option>
    <option value="/item2" selected>Item 2</option>
    <option value="/item3" selected>Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: On an iPad, when I tested it, it didn't work, but on Windows 8 it works. Any fixes?

Comment: I've added a possible fix for ipad, but I can't test it.  Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181/clear-all-fields-in-a-form-upon-going-back-with-browser-back-button)

Modern browsers implement something known as back-forward cache (BFCache). When you hit back/forward button the actual page is not reloaded (and the scripts are never re-run).

If you have to do something in case of user hitting back/forward keys -- listen for BFCache pageshow and pagehide events.

A pseudo jQuery example:

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
  // update hidden input field
});
```

Comment: Could you also call `location.reload();` in the `$(window).bind("pageshow")` function to make sure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top');this.value=''">
    <option value="" selected>Default Value</option>
    <option value="/item1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="/item2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="/item3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```