# Grails 2.5.x clear form after submit

Tags: html, grails, parameters

I'm working on `Grails 2.5.x`.

When I submit a form and save successful, I press back on browser and the data in form still there, it may screw up the data.

How can I clear the form by using `back-end`.

I try to clear `params` but it doesn't work.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181/clear-all-fields-in-a-form-upon-going-back-with-browser-back-button

Comment: Thanks you, but I need to handle it in back-end, not frond-end.