# Clear form data while pressing browser back button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching, back

I have a web form (page 1) which gets the input from the user and stores in database.

When I click save, after saving the data, it displays a message with application id in a new page (page 2).

If I click back button through browser, then it is going to that page 1 and displaying the input that I have given.

I want to prevent this. I disabled cache of the page 1, but when I click back this time I am getting web page has expired in IE.
But sometimes it is going to the previous page (page 1) and displaying input fields without a data.

Can anyone please help me how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear all fields in a form upon going back with browser back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181/clear-all-fields-in-a-form-upon-going-back-with-browser-back-button)

Comment: This question has been asked here a LOT* of times here, please use search. (*Sometimes I wonder if it's one of Top 10 duplicated questions)