# WFFM - How to clear or init form fields when press back button on browser?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a WFFM form, when I submit it to success and press back button on browser, the data still stay on the fields.
How I can clear or init form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this not a problem of Sitecore or WFFM. Modern browsers implement  back-forward cache. And I believe you will see same behavior on regular ASP.Net forms.

This happens due to browser don't actually refresh pages on back/forward buttons click.

To change this behavior you should add your custom JavaScript on page that will clear WFFM form fields. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181/clear-all-fields-in-a-form-upon-going-back-with-browser-back-button) could be useful.

Comment: you right, it just occurred with Chrome and my solution is prevent the browser re-filling again.
$("form").get(0).setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');