# Laravel 5.2 - back click shows only json data, refresh show full page

Tags: laravel

it seems it only caches the json call, so whenever me or my users hit window back, it only shows the json data i loadet.

Can i somehow force it to load all, or setup the cache to cache the whole page?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put `cache: false`, in my json and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Browser will load page from cache while hit back button. I placed some text and reference from [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181/clear-all-fields-in-a-form-upon-going-back-with-browser-back-button). See more details and implementation for [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) and [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/blog/427/webkit-page-cache-i-the-basics/).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is, i might just reload if for example body does not have class called loadet, but i have to run this function in EVERY  json request i make, must be another solution im not seeing? :-)