# Clear WebForms fields when user clicks back button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I'm finding it really difficult to figure out a way to clear my WebForms page fields when the user decides to click 'back'.

This is causing a few issues with users who are clicking back and then forwards again and as they are clicking back there is no Page_Load method being called, for me to initialise the fields.

This is a rather old project and I don't necessarily want to run a document.ready or something (which I'm also not entirely sure executes when moving back).

Is there any way I can detect a 'back' click in my code and automatically just reset the page?

Comment: Do you mean how to detect **Browser** Back Button event?

Answer (score 0):

`Page_Load` is not called because page is loaded from browsers cache.

You can disable it using `Response.Cache.SetNoStore();` or you could handle `pageshow` and `pagehide` events. See: [Clear all fields in a form upon going back with browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181/clear-all-fields-in-a-form-upon-going-back-with-browser-back-button)