# Textarea is not getting reset after browser back

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I have a nav-tab with 3 tabs and every tab has a form with a text area. After submitting the 2nd or 3rd form when I click the browser back my text area is clear, but when I submit the form in 1st tab the text area still contains the text. I need to clear it too.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Why would you want the browser to clear your data? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: check this article to know more about [browser back button](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/)

Comment: I want that my form doesn't show any text when I click back

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, you'd have to do this with JavaScript.

See: [Clear all fields in a form upon going back with browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181/clear-all-fields-in-a-form-upon-going-back-with-browser-back-button)

Comment: Hi, this is really just a comment or at best a link only answer. If you were to add some useful description about the problem and the solution it would become a valid answer

Comment: But it is a good Duplicate so I used it as such

Comment: My problem is different. I've nav tabs