# Clearing/ Emptying form data upon back button click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer

Say I have `Page A` that has a cool `POST` `form` that submits and then goes to `Page Z`.

Right now on `Page A`, I have `autocomplete='off'` on all `forms` and all `form inputs`.

Currently:

1. Go to `Page A` and submit the `form` with data.
2. See `Page Z` and hit the `back button` on the browser.
3. `Page A` has the form displayed with submitted data (from 1).

How do I clear the `form data` from `Page A` or prevent it from being shown when I click the `back button` on `Page Z`?

Note: the form data is being cleared in `Firefox` (except checkboxes) and `Chrome`, but not in `IE` (using 10 to debug). I would like all the form data from all types of input to be empty.

Comment: Already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649747/clear-form-on-back-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting it from the cache, make a form reset on load and your forms will be resetted to default values. I am doing it on 95% of my forms.

```
$('form').each(function() {
    this.reset();
});
```

This only apply to inputs inside a form.

Comment: Can you please share a snippet of code as an example?

Comment: This works great with Chrome and Firefox, but not appear to work with IE 11 or Edge.